# simple_html_dom Cannot add node in second level

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I cannot find my second level node, the object is empty

```
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");

$simple = new simple_html_dom();
$simple->load("<div id='base'>divbase</div>");
$base = $simple->find("#base",0);
echo $simple->outertext."<br>";
echo "base=".$base->innertext."<br>";
$base->innertext .= "<div id='div_1_'>div1</div>";
$ch = $simple->save();
echo $ch."<br>";
$trouv = $simple->find('#div_1_',0);
$trouv->innertext .= "<div id='div_1_0_'>some text</div>";
$ch = $simple->save();
echo $ch."<br>";
```

the var $trouv is empty why?

Comment: Show us the document you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you add `<div id='div_1_0_'>some text</div>` to the `innertext` but that is not being parsed as html.

What you might do is load the modified html again using  `$simple->load($simple->save());`

You code could look like:

```
$simple = new simple_html_dom();
$simple->load("<div id='base'>divbase</div>");
$base = $simple->find("#base",0);
echo $simple->outertext."<br>";
echo "base=".$base->innertext."<br>";
$base->innertext .= "<div id='div_1_'>div1</div>";
$simple->load($simple->save());
$ch = $simple->save();
echo $ch."<br>";
$trouv = $simple->find('#div_1_',0);
$trouv->innertext .= "<div id='div_1_0_'>some text</div>";
$ch = $simple->save();
echo $ch."<br>";
```